# Is an Underwater œcumenopolis viable?

Tags: science-fiction, underwater, arcology

An important planet in my setting is an ocean planet with a few atolls as its landmass. I intend the planet to be an underwater oecumenopolis (imagine a planet-spanning Rapture from Bioshock). Most buildings take their root into the ocean floor and goes up to the surface. The deepest regions are either covered in automated geothermal facilities or used as the planet's dumpsters.
Is this kind of of Oecumenopolis realistic and viable ? What maximum depth do you think could accept such arcologies (I intend the planet's ocean to be quite shallow in comparison with Earth) ?

Comment: Maybe. There exists one research facility: https://www.businessinsider.com/see-permanent-undersea-research-lab-world-florida-nasa-science-tech-research-nasa-2017-6?r=US&IR=T

Answer (score 3):

### Not very deep

It's good that you want more shallow oceans than Earth. A globe spanning web of underwater cities has three big problems. Pressure, air and light.

## Pressure

Pressure is easily obvious. Grab a habitat for one person. If you want to make it twice as big, you need much more structural strength to withstand the pressure on the hull. Just like making an A4 paper a kilometer big but the same thickness. It'll easily rip by just the wind. To withstand the new pressure, you need to do one or all of the following: more supports inside and outside, thicker walls and higher (air) pressure. The same applies for going deeper into the ocean. Submarines or habitats for the deep ocean are pressurised and the phrase 'build like a tank' is actually not enough to describe the hull.

Air pressures would quickly be different the deeper you go. Many air locks and pressure differences will make moving about difficult for both the speed as well as the human body.

The measures to withstand pressure makes making larger areas like a market square difficult, unless close to the surface. That means all means of mass transport needs to be at or close to the surface, or require many separate modules next to each other to withstand the pressure and allow enough space for transport. This increases cost by an insane margin.

## Light

Light is important for life. In the oceans you can see this incredibly well. In the shallow oceans life grows easily and abundantly. In deeper oceans close to shallow parts you can still see a lot of life floating about. But deep oceans are generally devoid of life. Light doesn't reach deep enough to hit the bottom and towards the surface there is too little sustenance to live with the light. Light is also an abundant energy source for electricity, though this can be skipped with big technologies. Even so you need a lot of light infrastructure the deeper you go to keep people healthy and able to see. Especially as you will use a lot of light for crops there will be little light left to go through.

## Air

As mentioned before, you need to pressurise the air the deeper you go to help withstand pressures. This has many dangers, like deep sea sickness from changing too quickly from high to low pressure. But it also represents an air problem. You need to recycle the air. Pumping deeper and deeper down requires more and more energy. You can make it easy and use, for example, electrolysis to create oxygen from water (and immediately have a storage medium for electricity. The hydrogen that is also released can be used to make electricity and heat by combining it with oxygen, making clean water! Though you need oxygen for this, making it a difficult relationship of power vs oxygen). The 'dirty' air can be released directly in the ocean and find it's own way up.

## Conclusion

How deep can you actually build? A quick search shows that the ocean's 'sunlight' zone is up to 200 meters, which sounds promising. Unfortunately light is already severely reduced at this point for human standards. Light only reaches so far 'under the right conditions', making it doubly doubtful it is useful for human habitation.

The pressure is a different story. Per meter of water you get just shy of 0,1 bar of pressure. At 10m you have just shy of 1 bar, which is very doable. At 50 about 5 and so on. It isn't impossible by far to make large modules to withstand those pressures, but it'll both be exponentially expensive and difficult to guarantee a lifetime of use. Especially if you want to make a good infrastructure you need expensive, extensive and incredibly difficult to create/maintain structures. Together with different air pressures I don't expect much deeper than 20m is feasible for a workable underwater village, let alone a city. Not to mention the waves at the surface giving a whole other dimension of difficulties.

I would say a not very deep city is the only feasible way to make a city under water. That is ignoring cost and resources.

Answer (score 3):

### The Problem is Heat

In any planet-wide city, there is an enormous amount of energy both generated and expended.

For modern-day cities, heat generation comes in the form of lighting, heating and cooling of buildings, manufacturing in industry, power generation and consumption, and all other technological processes that produce heat. Our cities currently are contained to relatively small proportions of the planets surface and pushed into the atmosphere, in your case **a planet-wide city would produce many orders of magnitude more heat**.

Could this be mitigated by your ocean somewhat? Perhaps, but **your ocean would essentially be a large conductor of heat, and also a heat sink**. Once hot, it's likely to not cool and loose its heat less than that of the world-wide cities production of heat. Likely this would spell disaster.

You may need to consider technological solutions to the discarding of heat - the good news is having a planet-wide ocean yields benefits due to the conductivity and heat-sink nature of water:

- consider large 'heat exchange' facilities that transfer heat to hot objects to be expelled from the planet, or exchanged with colder objects from space.
- perhaps consider large radiative panels to emit the heat out to space
- consider a large trade / commerce relationship with heat to nearby cooler planets

Also consider the ecology of the ocean may be severely affected by the city. We know in modern times a 1 - 2 degree ocean temperature rise would result in 30-40% underwater species loss (mainly coral reefs), perhaps consider this in your story and how it can be protected, and any other implications.

Answer (score 2):

is it possible? yes. but is there no other planet available? with our current technology we would rather build on a barren rock than build on the seafloor.

the idea of a œcumenopolis it that is a hub full of commerce, trade, research, governance and culture. a planet wide Los Angeles/New York/Detroit/Washington DC. usually a œcumenopolis imports raw resources and food and exports finished goods high-tech items and art. the most important question you would need to answer is: why go for the one location that is the most difficult to reach with an spaceship? while the current day examples all indicate that one would grow on the easiest to reach location.

Answer (score 1):

It seems plausible: water, with its buoyancy, can reduce the load on the structures and allow for taller buildings.

Keep in mind that the bottom of an ocean is, on Earth, a thermostat at 4 C (temperature at which water has its maximum density), which can be useful for dumping waste heat from your machinery.

It is also constantly dark, but if you don't plan on living there, it should not be an issue.

On Earth we can build structures as high as 800-ish meter; in places with not so strong water currents I think you can double that height, as you can also use floaters to further reduce the weight load on the structure.

Be careful with the dumpster concept: if you keep raising the floor by adding garbage, you will end up surrounded by cold water and garbage.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, natural light would be a serious concern. Here is a graph of the penetration of different natural light colors:

[image]

Below fifty meters in muddy, stirred-up coastal environments you will be living in night-time level darkness. Assuming this is an active city, they will need to seriously manage silt and dirt circulation to improve underwater visibility.

Thankfully, the size of an underwater continental shelf can be quite large. Look at the portion in the Pacific. Even if there were only scattered continental shelves like this, there could still be 2-20% of the world habitable with complex ocean city-building technologies. That is more than enough space for a vast civilization.

[image]

The civilization would likely focus first on expanding out the existing atolls and other land as far as possible. They could create artificial islands through dredging, underwater mining, and massive infrastructure projects. However, at some point it would be more economically feasible to build up from the seafloor, rather than raising the seafloor itself. Large engineered platforms for stone from the ocean floor could be built up in 50 meter high platforms for each building. The buildings would then have their tops emerge into the sunlight above. Causeways and other over-water bridges would connect the massive building-structures.

The underwater portion would still be useful, especially close to the surface. These could have windows and still receive light. Further down, by about 50 meters, and you are essentially "underground". Think about current underground infrastructure, and you have an idea of what you can have situated at these depths-- industry, storage, communications, less desirable habitations, processing, mining, ect.

There could also be underwater tunnels running between the bottoms of these buildings. It would be somewhat more economically feasible to build above-ground, and yet underwater tunnels, rather than simply carving through solid rock below the oceans.

So, you would have well-developed atolls, surrounded by huge expanses of continental shelf with buildings rising from the seafloor, connected by roads and causeways, with underwater structures connected by oceanfloor covered roadways and tunnels.

Agriculture, of course, would focus on fishing , seaweed farming (whatever local biological equivalent) and perhaps creation of giant algae mats, which can be processed for multiple nutrients. Perhaps some local woody substance could be harvested, dried, and burned for heat.

For a century or two they could exhaust carbon-heavy deposits for energy production (oil equivalents) before running out. Of course the opportunities for wind power are enormous. Floating solar panels might cover significant portions of the more "open sea" portion of the world. This would disrupt local wildlife, presumably, so there would be concerns by conservationists and environmentalists.

All in all, yes, there are some real possibilities for your ocean metropolis. It is not the most efficient world to settle, but it is does sound like an interesting and beautiful one.